# Mapping table join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables as follows,

```
student
category
student_category
```

Student table has the following columns:

```
studentid, student name, studenttype
```

Category table has the following tables:

```
categoryid, categoryname, ..
```

student_category table has the following columns:

```
id, studentid, categoryid
```

Now I have 2 input parameters `categoryid and studenttype` so now I need to get the all the student details which are associated with respective `categoryid` and whose student type is `studenttype`

I tried as follows which is not giving correct result,

```
SELECT
    s.*
FROM
    student s 
    JOIN 
    student_category sc ON sc.categoryid = 1;
```

Also I also need to filter student whose `studenttype` is 'someinput'

I am working on PostgreSQL. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `where` clause and also use the appropiate `join` condition.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM student s 
JOIN student_category sc ON sc.studentid = s.studentid
where s.studenttype = 'studenttype' --or your desired value
and sc.categoryid = 1
```